# I need to include a time in the from_date option in a DocuSign envelope status change request

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to get envelope status changes using the DocuSign API. I am using the following URL in my request:

> ```
> {url}/restapi/v2/accounts/<account id>/envelopes?from_date=1%2F6%2F2015+12:46:00+PM&from_to_status=changed
> ```

An envelope was created at 3:46:11 PM ET, but it appears the only way I can get envelope information about it (other than using the envelope Id, which I'd rather not do) is to specify 12:46:00 PM as shown in the above example.  Of course the time zone is not included in the URL, but it appears that my requests only work if I specify the time in Pacific Time (PT).  If I use my local time (3:46 PM ET), or universal time (8:46 PM UTC) I get zero results.

I have tried going into my Preferences at DocuSign and changing my time zone to UTC, but that didn't change anything (and there is a note at the Preferences page saying "The time zone functionality is only available for the current user interface", so I suppose it didn't work for good reason.

Going forward should I always use Pacific Time (PST8PDT) in my requests?

---

**In response to Andrew's suggestion**

I changed my Time Zone Used for API to UTC and tried this again.  I got the somewhat similar results.  I sent a request for signature at 12:56 PM ET, and got a statusDateTime of `2015-01-08T01:56:38.9500000Z`, which is tomorrow morning in London, 13 hours after the request time.  When I send a request using Pacific, time, I get a valid result.  Here is the request:

> ```
> {URL}/restapi/v2/accounts/<account id>/envelopes?from_date=1%2F7%2F2015+9:56:00+AM&from_to_status=changed
> ```

But when I send a request using UTC or my local time (ET) I get no result.

I also tried changing the request time to the format Andrew posted a few moments ago, as follows:

> ```
> {{baseUrl}}/v2/accounts/<account id>/envelopes?from_date=2015-01-07T09:56:00&from_to_status=changed
> ```

That works, but only if I specify pacific time (9:56 AM as opposed to my local 12:56 PM ET, or 17:56 PM UTC).

Andrew asked that I share a picture of the features settings within the DocuSign preferences.  Unfortunately StackOverflow won't let me post graphics until I have a "reputation" of 10 or greater, so I have placed the image at this link: https://app.box.com/s/ab3s45fp5sco2k41mn74

Edited Image In:
[image]

In addition, here is a log of a request for signature that I made just now:

```
STEP 1:  Sending Login request at 2015-01-08T11:58:03.936-05:00...

-- Login response --

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><loginInformation xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <loginAccounts>
    <loginAccount>
      <accountId>account id</accountId>
      <baseUrl>https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/account id</baseUrl>
      <email>email address</email>
      <isDefault>true</isDefault>
      <name>self</name>
      <siteDescription/>
      <userId>user id</userId>
      <userName>william asher</userName>
    </loginAccount>
  </loginAccounts>
</loginInformation>


STEP 2:  Sending signature request from template...

-- Signature Request response --

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><envelopeSummary xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <envelopeId>envelope id</envelopeId>
  <status>sent</status>
  <statusDateTime>2015-01-09T00:58:05.9530000Z</statusDateTime>
  <uri>/envelopes/envelope id</uri>
</envelopeSummary>

Signature requests have been sent to [email addresses]!
EnvelopeId is:  envelope id
```

Here is a status request with the time in ET in it:

> {{url}}/v2/accounts/account id/envelopes?from_date=2015-01-08T11:58:00&from_to_status=changed

Here is the response:

```
{
    "resultSetSize": "0",
    "totalSetSize": "0",
    "nextUri": "",
    "previousUri": "",
    "envelopes": []
}
```

Here is a status request with with the time in PT in it:

> {{url}}/v2/accounts/account id/envelopes?from_date=2015-01-08T08:58:00&from_to_status=changed

Here is the result:

```
{
    "resultSetSize": "1",
    "totalSetSize": "1",
    "startPosition": "0",
    "endPosition": "0",
    "nextUri": "",
    "previousUri": "",
    "envelopes": [
        {
            "status": "sent",
            "documentsUri": "/envelopes/envelope id/documents",
            "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/envelope id/recipients",
            "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/envelope id",
            "envelopeId": "envelope id",
            "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/envelope id/custom_fields",
            "notificationUri": "/envelopes/envelope id/notification",
            "statusChangedDateTime": "2015-01-08T16:58:05.9530000Z",
            "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/envelope id/documents/combined",
            "certificateUri": "/envelopes/envelope id/documents/certificate",
            "templatesUri": "/envelopes/envelope id/templates"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is a status request with the time in UTC:

> {{url}}/v2/accounts/account id/envelopes?from_date=2015-01-08T16:58:00&from_to_status=changed

Here is the result:

```
{
    "resultSetSize": "0",
    "totalSetSize": "0",
    "nextUri": "",
    "previousUri": "",
    "envelopes": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting in Features called **Time Zone used for API**, you can specify your desired result there.

[image]

Here is my sample create and get changed status

Call

```
GET: https://{server}/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes?from_date=2015-01-07T07:42:00&to_date=2015-01-10T00:00:00&status=Completed&from_to_status=Sent
```

Response

```
{
  "resultSetSize": "1",
  "totalSetSize": "1",
  "startPosition": "0",
  "endPosition": "0",
  "nextUri": "",
  "previousUri": "",
  "envelopes": [
    {
      "status": "completed",
      "documentsUri": "/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents",
      "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients",
      "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/{envelopeId}",
      "envelopeId": "{envelopeId}",
      "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/{envelopeId}/custom_fields",
      "notificationUri": "/envelopes/{envelopeId}/notification",
      "statusChangedDateTime": "2015-01-07T17:42:34.5970000Z",
      "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/combined",
      "certificateUri": "/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/certificate",
      "templatesUri": "/envelopes/{envelopeId}/templates"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: When I change the time zone for API to UTC, my signature request gets a statusDateTime 9 hours earlier than my local time.  For example, I sent the request at 12:09:34 PM ET, and the statusDateTime returned was 2015-01-08T01:09:34.1330000Z.  When I subsequently request status for changed items after 17:09 PM UTC (which is the current UTC time), I get no results.

Comment: I just changed mine to UTC and tested an envelope and get normal results. Could you update your original post with your updated request after the timezone change?

Comment: @WilliamAsher could you take a screenshot of your accounts Time settings like I did and post it? I'm wondering what is differing between our tests

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when polling the SOAP API for getting the updates of the Envelopes for 15 minute Intervals.

We have our App running in EST. when we try to get the updates on Enveloped for my account in the last 15 minutes we don't get the updates, but if I use the PST time we are getting the updates even though the "Time Zone used for API" is set to EST.
E.g. If I create an Envelope at 7PM EST, If I try to call RequestStatusEx Method with the Time Interval 6:55PM and 7:10PM, I will not get any updates. If I use 3:55PM and 7:10PM I get the updates, seems like it is using PST and all our Servers are in EST.